# Problems with advertising in android

Tags: android, admob

I have developed an application (that is currently in play google) and put advertising goes wrong.

I put screenshots to give you an idea.

1º Start the application and advertising is normal, and when pressed on EditText (Text) is normal and usually stops writing.

1º--- https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VTgL.png

The problem is when I switch activity or advertising to visit again and hit the same EditText (Text) is blocked by advertising as this up and EditText stays at the site.
![advertising now rises up and not eddittext][3]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/j35Nw.png

Here me xml activity:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/Biniciar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Etitulo"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:src="@drawable/micro" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/ETexto"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ETexto"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="@string/Texto"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/anuncio"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Etitulo"
        android:text="@string/Titulo"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Bborrar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/Limpiar" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/BAdmin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/Notas" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Etitulo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Bborrar"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/BGuardar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/Guardar" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ETexto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Etitulo"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Biniciar"
        android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:maxLines="5" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you need to manage your xml file design

Comment: can you put here your xml file

Comment: Of course, now u can see me xml, the advertising is the linear layout "anuncio". Thx

Answer (score 0):

Your original layout without the keyboard happens to work with the ads because the rest of your content doesn't fill the entire page. A best practice would be, in addition to aligning the ad to the bottom, to tell the rest of your layout to sit abobve the ad.

```
<RelativeLayout>
  <LinearLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:id="@+id/anuncio"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="60dp"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:background="#FFFFFF" >
  </LinearLayout>
  <RelativeLayout
      android:id="@+id/restOfMyLayout"
      android:layout_above="@id/anuncio">
      // Put the rest of your layout here.
  </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

If you do this, the ad won't cover your textbox.

Comment: Thx, now i have differents layouts, but now look like this when i go another activity and come back. Now everything goes up http://imgur.com/9IVkD9W